# how to write script for same procedure for all same class element up to end?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new in selenium webdriver with java. I have `<a class="row-title">` property up to 21 web element.I want to do code in loop so i can merge java selenium code in to small, currently i have to write same script for all 21 test. Ex.

```
<a class="row-title">1</a>>
........
........
<a class="row-tilte">21</a>.

also i have to do same clicking and update procedure up to 1 to 21 


package Dev_admin;
import java.nio.channels.SelectableChannel;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
public class present extends login{
@Test(priority = 1)
public void update1() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='post-1217']/td[1]/strong/a")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu-posts-presentation']/a/div[3]")));
    element.click();
        }
@Test(priority = 2)
public void update2(){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='post-1139']/td[1]/strong/a")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    WebElement element = 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//* 
    [@id='menu-posts-presentation']/a/div[3]")));
    element.click();        


//if i am using class name instead of x path , then how to do same procedure 
in loop so my code became so small or merged..

@Test(priority = 1)
    public void update1() {
    driver.findElement(By.className("row-title")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    WebElement element = 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//* 
    [@id='menu-posts-presentation']/a/div[3]"))); 
    element.click();
        }

@Test(priority = 2)
   public void update2(){
   driver.findElement(By.className("row-title")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    WebElement element = 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//* 
    [@id='menu-posts-presentation']/a/div[3]")));
    element.click();        
}
```

Comment: You should use `findElements` that gives you a list of elements... now you can just loop thru it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `findElements` which retrieve the list of elements. Then go for looping those one by one.

```
List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.className("row-title"));

for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {

        elements.get(i).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        WebElement element = 
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu-posts-presentation']/a/div[3]")));
        element.click();
    }
```